# Is there a variable which can limit usability of sessions in a folder to certain files?

Tags: php, session, ssl, permissions, path

I have PHP application, created by someone else. Each section is one php file. I want to extend it by another section, but each time I create php file for the new section, that file shows an error of session_start:

> open(/var/lib/php5/sess_*somecode*, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied
> (13)
>
> Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current
> setting of session.save_path is correct

The file contains the same php code as another page/section which goes well. Link to that file is correct as well, it still links to file on http://domain.com which is default setting, not http://www.domain.com. It behaves like there is some list/array of names of files which are only allowed to store session in tmp folder. When I create new one it isn't in that list/array, so it shows this warning. Like I don't have permission to create new file and use the same session in it.

Is there something like that list/array I'm looking for, or I'm searching absolutely out of the way?

Comment: This reeks of a deeper issue. For example, I have had stuff like this when switching between two PHP versions - one running as a CGI binary, and one running as an Apache module. If the different PHP versions have different user rights, there can be problems continuing a session. Do you have a sysadmin you can ask about this? You are never using `www.domain.com`?

Comment: Yes I have. And when I use www.domain.com it shows that error in each file. I supposed it was something with session configuration options in php.ini, however this happens only in one subfolder of domain. Others run without any problem. This is weird part of it.

Comment: do you have a .htaccess file in that subfolder, possibly with `AddHandler` instructions in them?

Comment: No I don't have .htaccess there at all.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm sure this has a simple reason but *finding* it is the hard part... I would talk to the sysadmin next, maybe they know something.

Comment: This problem I've seen when the server/mount is out of disk space or when the location does not exist. It may not be as simple as permissions. However I would add a sleep(300) after the session start and check "top" in linux to see which user is trying to write to the file and then see if they have permission.